# AspNet Core Logging working but not inside ServiceStack services when hosted in Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a simple ServiceStack service with some logging added.

```
log.Info("In Vehicle service request");
if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
    log.Debug("Debugging Vehicle service request");
```

log is defined in a base class as follows;

```
public abstract class ServiceBase : Service
{
    public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ServiceBase));
}
```

The web host is configured to add various logging providers, including log4net (NOTE: I have tried others = same problem).

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    config
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables();     //lets Azure portal override settings
                    context.Configuration = config.Build();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                    logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
                    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
                    // The ILoggingBuilder minimum level determines the
                    // the lowest possible level for logging. The log4net
                    // level then sets the level that we actually log at.
                    logging.AddLog4Net();
                    //logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                })
                .UseAzureAppServices()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

The ServiceStack AppHost sets the LogFactory early as follows;

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //Also runs log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
    LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(configureLog4Net: true);
..etc
```

What happens?

I get lovely logging if I add some in my StartUp.  However the logging in the ServiceStack service does not appear when hosted in Azure.  I do get logging when running locally.

So NetCore is logging ok, but anything in the Service class is not!

Why no logging with this?

```
public async Task<GetMyDataResponse> Any(GetMyData request)
        {
            log.Info("In service request");
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
                log.Debug("Debugging service request");

            //Some request validation logic could/should go here.
            return new GetMyDataResponse
            {
                Results = await _myDataRepo.FetchAsync()
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was a silly routing issue, matching to a method in a Controller instead of falling into the ServiceStack route as defined on the interface model.  A method I'd left hanging around when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try either configuring the LogFactory before ServiceStack isinitialized, e.g:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(configureLog4Net: true);

    app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost
    {
        AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
    });
}
```

Or use an instance logger in your Services:

```
public readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ServiceBase));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that and no success.  Getting plenty of other logging so I can see the authentication debugging, controllers being invoked and even the entity framework sql.  Just not those manually logging requests.  I do get the entries being logged if run locally on my PC.  Push to Azure, and they are not appearing.  It feels like its not picking up any config file, like its not getting passed to SS somehow.

Comment: Can you find out what the Type name of the logger is?